# Website ranking services such as Similarweb and Alexa don't recognize my site

Tags: wordpress, alexa, rank-checkers

I have my WordPress website added on Google Search Console. Here is a screenshot of it: [image: google search console screenshot]

Google Analytics works fine too. Sitemap has also been submitted and I can clearly see my daily traffic. The site and URL have been active for about 2 months. But I don't get any result when I search for my site on similarweb.com or Alexa whereas I can clearly see another domain that I purchased quite recently and that website has practically no traffic, no sitemap has been submitted, no Google Analytics either.

Am I doing something with the settings here? I know some other month old websites which are being crawled by Alexa and Similarweb. Do I need to add my webpages to these seo sites?
Any advice appreciated.

Comment: These are junk websites that have negative value, why do you want their attention or even care at all??

Comment: @closetnoc Really? I am just starting to work on SEO for my website. Since everyone around me cared so much, I assumed alexa listings brought some value.

Comment: After a little more research on this forum, I have come to realize that I shouldnt really worry about alexa rankings. Thank you @closetnoc, I like it when i dont have to care.

Comment: This might be a great opportunity to educate people on Alexa and how these other junk sites add no particular value. Most of us believe that the various SEO sites are junk and should not be relied upon or seek value from them.

Answer (score 4):

Alexa, SimilarWeb, ContextWeb, Compete and the like are quite literally *useless* if the site in question is doing less than 250k uniques per month.

On 2 of the sites I own, which I can see in Analytics are doing 100k-150k uniques per month, these third party tools say I'm doing anywhere from 25k-250k uniques per month.   The data is all over the place.  They are firing blind, and they don't even come close to each other.

Their systems for estimating traffic are based on toolbars and limited pools of data and are useless for lower traffic sites.

I also have a site that does around 30k-50k unique users per month, and it doesn't show up on SimilarWeb either, but does show up on Alexa and Compete.

If you're doing <1000 uniques per month, it's not even on their radar.

Answer (score 1):

This is because your website or blog doesn't get enough web traffic. First you have to share your posts or pages on social media. Then you have to create good quality back links for your blog posts or website pages.

Answer (score 0):

for alexa

firstly you need to install alexa toolbar on the browser that yuo frequently use
and then use it to frequently browse your website
after 2 weeks the stats will start appearing on alexa

for similarweb
you need more traffic in order for them to even care to display your stats

Comment: First you install the Alexa toolbar to join in along with the select few web developers, site administrators and marketing geeks who intensely care about SEO and Alexa. You then use it to browse your website and hope that some of the other Alexa SEO aficionados care enough to browse your website too. Then Alexa cobbles together some statistics that appear and you develop that feelgood for accomplishing the human equivalent of a NOP instruction. It's not a sampling of the general web population, relevance is questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Your site is too smal to be recognized by alexa. Grow some more traffic, get thousands, 51 click on webmaster tool way too small. Or maybe you can register your site to alexa, similar to registering your web to google webmaster tool.

And also, on your image, you have lots of 404, try fixing it to increase your traffic.

Comment: Now that we are talking about the 51 clicks here.  search console has always displayed 51 as far as i can remember. The actual google analytics traffic says its atleast 500 pageviews a day ( after filtering out the bots) I have no idea why this would say 51 clicks here.

Comment: Also, I think the 404s are because the site went through permalinks changes and what not initially but all the pages on my site work fine. Is there still a need to fix these 404s? Maybe these 404s will go away if delete the current submitted sitemap and submit again?Thanks

Comment: Search console analytic always delayed around 2-3 days, not real time like GA. Even with GA, search query also delayed for a couple days. 500 pageviews is small, try to get 1000 UV maybe the alexa will start picking up. If you want alexa picking up now, try register your site on it. For 404, try to delete the list on search console (mark it as resolved), wait for few days, if it's apprearing again, you need to check if it's because permalink or not. Old backlink also causing 404. Fix the backlink or do premanent redirect to fix this. I think sitemap always update, is it not?